# How to "go back" on paginated items

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple collection which I would like to paginate.
I want to sort it and paginate it by a timestamp doc called `createdAt`.

This is how the call currently looks like:

```
function getPaginatedItems (db, startAfter) {
  return db
    .collection('items')
    .orderBy('createdAt')
    .startAfter(startAfter) // startAfter parameter will be a createdAt Timestamp doc
    .limit(3)
    .get()
}
```

To make this easier to work with and display, I created a function that will turn this query snapshot into a paginated object. This looks something like this:

```
function querySnapshotToPaginatedObject (querySnapshot, total, limit = 3) {   if (querySnapshot.empty) {
    return {
      total: 0,
      limit,
      data: []
    }
  } else {
    return {
      total,
      limit,
      data: querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

As it stands I have a total of 11 items in my firestore, but would like to get them in chunks of three. This all works perfectly when moving forward with the data, however my question then becomes, how do I go back? That is, how do I get data from the previous pages?

Currently what I have in my hands is the total number of items I have, the limit which can be displayed and obviously the three items I am currently displaying.

I have no idea how to keep track of all other ones in order to jump back pages, or jump more than one page for that matter.

So I guess there are two questions here: how do I go back to previous data? And how could I jump different chunks of data?

Is there another way to do this, perhaps by index instead of a specific doc (like I am doing with createdAt)?

Edit: I was asked how I am making my next queries. Basically I have buttons (all with their page numbers) and when I click on them, I do a second call starting with the `createdAt` attribute of the last item. I then do a second call to my initial query, but passing in the last object as the `startAfter` parameter in the `getPaginatedItems` function call.

I am using react as the front-end, so it looks something like this:

```
getNextBatch (startAfter) {
  return { 
    paginatedItems: querySnapshotToPaginatedObject(
      await getPaginatedItems(db, startAfter), 11, 3
    )
  } 
}

...
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component (
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.paginatedItem.map(x => <div>{x.name} {x.createdAt}</div>)}

        <button onClick={(evt) => console.warn('How do I go back???')}>
          Back
        </button>
        <button onClick={(evt) => getNextBatch(paginatedItem[paginatedItem - 1].createdAt)}>
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    )  
  }
)
```

Keep in mind that the component does re-render every time I click the buttons.

Comment: How exactly are you paging forward?  You're showing the first query, but not how you make subsequent queries.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have made an edit showing both the code and giving a brief explanation.

Comment: looking briefly... I would assume limit can take multiple params (look at the documetation). usually you can pass a `start`, `stop` set or a `limit`, `start` set. Your first start stop might be 0,3, second might be 3,6 (this may vary depending on implementation).  pass what page of pagination you are going to and calculate you start stop

Comment: Does endBefore work for you? It's described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore APIs don't provide a way to page backward.  The easiest thing to do in your case is to remember a list of `startAfter` values that you've used to fetch each page.  Each value will represent a page of data.  With that, going back to a previous page is just a matter of find the desired `startAfter` value from that list, then making the query with that.

To be honest, though, your total data set is pretty small, and it's probably not worth paging at all.  I'd just get the whole thing and keep it in memory.  Paging probably don't become worthwhile until you reach hundreds or thousands of documents (depending on how big each document is, of course, and how much memory you expect to have available).

Comment: To be clear, my data set is not going to stay that small. I just brought it up for the sake of the example.
Ideally, I would have liked to just use `startAt` and `endAt` and pass in the index of whatever, but that isn't working. I always get the same entries regardless of the number, so I am guessing that isn't correct either?

Comment: Keeping track of what element is the first of what page is out of the question as items are added and removed on a regular basis. If I could get it to just be a number, that would be ideal.

Comment: If items are constantly moving around with respect to the overall query, then paging isn't going to help you out very much at all.  What you need in that case is a single live query with a snapshot observer that gives you a callback whenever the query results change.  However, there is no paging available in this case.  You have to choose - do you want live query results when the results change over time, or do you want paging?  You can't have both together.

Comment: The objective here would simply be to show little bits of data (of my results) instead of one gigantic list. For this example, I would like to bring in 3 items at the time, and then when the user clicks `Next` they get the next three.
The data will occasionally change, but not to the point the user will see it doing so on screen, it just does so enough that I can't count on an item always being on the same page.

Comment: Again, paging will not help you very much, as your pages will change over time, and items of data could get skipped or duplicated depending on what happens when. You need something stable to work with for paging to make sense.